# Php array iteration

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array :

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 5877
            [parent_id] => 5862
            [label] => Railbikes
            [name] => railbikes
            [icon] => books.svg
            [level] => 5
            [tab_id] => 353
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 5756
            [parent_id] => 5754
            [label] => Tournaments
            [name] => tournaments
            [icon] => books.svg
            [level] => 5
            [tab_id] => 354
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 5756
            [parent_id] => 5754
            [label] => Tournaments
            [name] => tournaments
            [icon] => books.svg
            [level] => 5
            [tab_id] => 357
        )
```

In this array label => Tournaments repeats twice and this is the case for whole array many labels are repeating twice , thrice and many time .
I want this array to be shown like that there will be a unique label and there is tab_id in each array which is different . This tab_id sholdd be appended to the unique label .
The final array should look like this .

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 5877
                [parent_id] => 5862
                [label] => Railbikes
                [name] => railbikes
                [icon] => books.svg
                [level] => 5
                [tab_id] => 353
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 5756
                [parent_id] => 5754
                [label] => Tournaments
                [name] => tournaments
                [icon] => books.svg
                [level] => 5
                [tab_id] => 354 , 357
            )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? If it's from an SQL query consider adding `DISTINCT` on `entity_id` and a `GROUP_CONCAT` on `tab_id`.

Comment: Can we see your PHP Code ?

Comment: `[tab_id] => 354 , 357` is not valid syntax, it should be either a sub array, either a string

Comment: I don't see a question. I see the data that you have and the format you want it in. Do you want the code required to change one to the other? If yes, how are you getting the data and what have you tried so far? If no, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$new_array = array();
$items = array();

foreach( $array as $item )
{
    $check = array_search( $item['entity_id'], $items, true ); 
    if ( $check === false )
    {
        $temp = $item;
        $temp['tab_id'] = array( $item['tab_id'] );
        $new_array[] = $temp;
        $items[] = $temp['entity_id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $new_array[$check]['tab_id'][] = $item['tab_id'];
    }
}
```

where `$array` is your original array the you showed us. You can replace it at the end with `$array = $new_array;` if you want to keep the same name in the rest of the code.

Also, keep in mind that `tab_id` is now an `array` to fit with your requirement.

If you really want to keep it as in your example, you could use

```
$new_array = array();
$items = array();

foreach( $array as $item )
{
    $check = array_search( $item['entity_id'], $items, true ); 
    if ( $check === false )
    {
        $new_array[] = $item;
        $items[] = $item['entity_id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $new_array[$check]['tab_id'] .= ', '.$item['tab_id'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(1 => array
    (
        entity_id => 5877,
        parent_id => 5862,
        label => Railbikes,
        name => railbikes,
        icon => books.svg,
        level => 5,
        tab_id => 353
    ),

2 => array
    (
        entity_id => 5756,
        parent_id => 5754,
        label => Tournaments,
        name => tournaments,
        icon => books.svg,
        level => 5,
        tab_id => 354
    ),

3 => array
    (
        entity_id => 5756,
        parent_id => 5754,
        label => Tournaments,
        name => tournaments,
        icon => books.svg,
        level => 5,
        tab_id => 357
    )
    );


    print("<pre>");
    foreach ($arr AS $key => $value){
        /*foreach ($value AS $innerKey => $innerValue){

        }*/

        if($arr[$key]['label']  == $arr[$key-1]['label'] )
        {
            $newArr[$key-1]['tab_id'] = $arr[$key]['tab_id'].",". $arr[$key-1]['tab_id'];
        }
        else{
            $newArr[$key]= $arr[$key];
        }
    }
            print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: For the first $key there is no $key-1 value, you would add a condition for that. Also, this only works providing that the 2 objects with the same label are listed one after the other. And knowing that he has an entity_id, you should probably use that for identification and not the label.

Comment: I had used label as he has mentioned label as a unique value... for universal solution i need to test with the different cases...

Comment: 2 more hick-ups: you should initiate $newArr, and if there is a duplicate you skip a $key when adding to $newArr (this can have issues if he has 3 items with the same label, as the third won't be added)

Answer (score 0):

If the entity_id is always the same then you can 'cheat' a bit:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item)
{
    if(!isset($new_array[$item['entity_id']]) $new_array[$item['entity_id']] = $item;
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```

PS: Always try to prevent double data, doesn't make your script faster ;)

Comment: Is this line if(!isset($new_array[$item['entity_id']]) $new_array[$item['entity_id']] = $item; written correctly ?

Comment: And I can use this by adding distinct to query , but my main goal is to combine tab_is as I have mentioned above .

Comment: Seems like it's missing a closing `)` just before `$new_array[$item['entity_id']] = $item;`